# Jquery html() to div doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

..I suppose because the html has script tags :-/

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('.ad_slot').html('<scr'+'ipt type="text/javascript"><!-- amazon_ad_tag = "xxxxxxxx-xx"; amazon_ad_width = "160"; amazon_ad_height = "600"; //--></scr'+'ipt>');        
}); 
</script>

<div class="ad_slot"></div>
```

without the script tags the html displays fine. Is there any way to make this work with the tags included?

I need to generate a full js code using js for a project I'm working on.

I've also added the code to jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/c68wu/ although I'm not sure if scripts will show in the result window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Script tags are going to be stripped out if you attempt to add them with html.  Use
[jQuery.getScript()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) instead.

Comment: Thanks! I think you;re on to something! I tried like so `$('.ad_slot').getScript('<scr'+'ipt type="text\/javascr'+'ipt"> amazon_ad_tag = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx-xxx"; amazon_ad_width = "160"; amazon_ad_height = "600"; <\/scr'+'ipt>');` but I get `$(".ad_slot").getScript is not a function`

Comment: getScript() is an asynchronous call to a javascript file.  You cannot call your script the way you are trying to.  Get rid of the script tags and put the amazon_... stuff in its own file, then call getScript() on that file.  You are not using getScript correctly anyway.  It is $.getScript(url);  notice call of getScript on jQuery object; it cannot be applied to a selector.

Comment: Oh I see! Thank you! I'll experiment with it :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to escape slash in the closing script tag:

```
$('.ad_slot').html('...<\/script>');
```

Comment: It doesnt matter about the forward slash - I have included many tags in the html() function, and all tags involve a slash to close. Ive never had a problem.

Comment: @ClarkeyBoy you clearly never included `<script>` tag then, because it wouldn't work without escaping slash.

Comment: I just put all my script tags at the top - I take note of what **could** appear on the page, and include the jquery which applies to it by default - that way all the scripts stay in one place, where they should be - the Head tag...

Comment: Ok I'll admit you were right... I assumed that rules which apply to one tag also apply to all others. Could you edit your answer (just add a space or something) so that I can up-vote it again?

Comment: ta... sorry about the confusion. im always being told "never assume, always check"... maybe I should take a hint from this... lol

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to escape the forward slashes:

```
$('.ad_slot').html('<scr'+'ipt type="text\/javascript"><!-- amazon_ad_tag = "xxxxxxxx-xx"; amazon_ad_width = "160"; amazon_ad_height = "600"; \/\/--><\/scr'+'ipt>');
```

Or this:

```
$('.ad_slot').html('<script type="text/javascript">amazon_ad_tag = "xxxxxxxx-xx"; amazon_ad_width = "160"; amazon_ad_height = "600";</script>');
```

I removed the HTML comment tags and the + in script tags. Oh yeah, and I removed the escaping on the slashes...not needed.

Also, you may want to look at when your script to generate the ads is being loaded and run. I suspect it's run before and never sees this code.

Comment: I don't think your code will actually do anything since there is nothing to trigger anything. There are just some variables.

Comment: Sorry, the script is longer, I just posted the part I can;t figure out. Removing the + in script tags causes an unterminated string literal error. Removing the comment tags however is necessary, thanks :)